# Using leaflet and need to update component. How can I update the values in my constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using leaflet in my react component, and I'm using a scriptLoading library to load all the necessary scripts.

I have the following in my constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.map = null;
    this.popup = null;
  }
```

I am loading leaflet like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps({ isScriptLoaded, isScriptLoadSucceed }) {
    if (isScriptLoaded && !this.props.isScriptLoaded) {
      if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {
        this.map = L.map(this.refs.map);

   ///////
        this.popup = L.popup();
   ///////
```

However, I have a function inside my class that handles a `onClickMap(e)` and `this.map` and `this.popup` are always null.  In my render function, `this.map` and `this.popup` are not null.

```
onClickMap(event) {
    console.log('on click', this.popup, this.map);  // both null
    if (this.popup) {
      this.popup
        .setLatLng(event.latlng)
        .setContent('You clicked the map at ' + event.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(this.map);
    }
  }
```

How can I update the constructor values correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this.state` in your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        map: null,
        popup: null
    }
}
```

And use `setState` in componentWillReceiveProps.

```
componentWillReceiveProps({ isScriptLoaded, isScriptLoadSucceed }) {
    if (isScriptLoaded && !this.props.isScriptLoaded) {
      if (isScriptLoadSucceed) {        
        this.setState({
            map: L.map(this.refs.map),
            popup: L.popup()
        });
   ///////
```

And you can get it from `this.state`.

```
onClickMap(event) {
    console.log('on click', this.state.popup, this.state.map);  // both null
    if (this.state.popup) {
      this.state.popup
        .setLatLng(event.latlng)
        .setContent('You clicked the map at ' + event.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(this.state.map);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks!  If you don't mind can you please explain when to use constructor then?

Comment: @user1354934 Check this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: what would be the best way to implement this then?  http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/ . where would you put the `onMapClick` from that?

Comment: I don't understand. There is no problem `onMapClick` inside your class.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for your help I understand it now :) . I am just wondering how would you do it.  Using state?

Comment: Yes, state or props(stateless) depends on your needs.